# Allocate minimum number of pages to each student

Tags: algorithm

Please can anyone give the proper algorithm to solve this question. Not the code just algorithm. Thank you.

> You are given N number of books. Every ith book has Pi number of pages.
> You have to allocate books to M number of students so that maximum number of pages alloted to a student is minimum. A book will be allocated to exactly one student. Each student has to be allocated atleast one book.
>
> Note: Return -1 if a valid assignment is not possible, and allotment should be in contiguous order.

Here's [a link](http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=448) to problem statement.

Comment: Hi any correct answers or approach discussions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the maximum to X pages per student.

To check if this is feasible just start allocating books to the first student until the next book would push over the threshold X. Then switch to the next and so on (this works because they say the allocations need to be contiguous).

If you run out of books then it's feasible (you can always go back and give students less books to read to fit the other students). If you run out of students then it's not.

This check will be O(N) where N is the number of books.

Now that you have this, do a binary search for X. Complexity is O(NlogM) where N is the number of books and M is the total number of pages.

Comment: Hi Sorin, how do you determine X?

Comment: You do a binary search.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, So i will explain what @Sorin in the above post meant.

Our basic approach is set an upper limit and then check if we can allocate books to students based on this upper limit ,i.e. check If allocation is really possible ?

For eg- Say we have 12 , 67 , 34 , 90 as our four books with their value indicating the number of pages in that book. And suppose number of students we have is 2.
And say that I set upper limit to 20(suppose).
Now lets start allocating books to our students .

1. Allocate first book with 12 pages to student 1 (This is feasible as max limit is 20 pages per student).
2. Try allocating book with 67 pages to student 1 again but this becomes unfeasible as now total becomes 12+67 = 79 which exceeds the upper limit i.e. 20.
3. So now allocate 67 pages book to 2nd student which again becomes unfeasible as limit is exceeded again .
4. Now since their are no students left . Thus this means that we estimated our upper limit incorrectly .
5. So now we increase the upper limit again lets say to 113 and then all the books are allocated to the students .

Okay so now what remains is how to find this upper limit .

Answer - Binary Search .

Explanation -

1. set l = 0 , r = Integer.MAX_VALUE , mid(upper limit) = (l+r)/2 .
2. check the above explained algo with this upper limit .

   a. if this value is accepted based on the algo . set r = mid-1(i.e. check if it works on a smaller limit).

   b. if this value is not accepted set l = mid+1(i.e. check if it works on a higher limit).

3.do this until l < r.

(Note )- Initially check if (number of students> books) return -1;

Comment: Great explanation, only thing to change is l = min(inputArray), r = sum(inputArray) !!

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic example of binary search the answer.
So you need to make an observation : 
if you increase the number of students(M), the maximum number of pages(P_max) to be allocation decreases.
The minimum of P_max(lo) will occur when M = N. Answer being maximum value of all P_i. 
The maximum of P_max(hi) will occur when M = 1. Answer being the sum of all P_i.

Now, we define a function F(x) which will return true if we can allocate at most maximum x pages to each student and still satisfy at most M student.

F(x) can be calculated by traversing the pages array(P) and increasing the count of the number of students by 1 if we can allocate a contiguous sum of x pages starting from the first book.

Let us call F(x) as allocateBooks function.
The parameters being pages array(P), number of books(n), maximum number of pages(x) and number of students(m).

```
bool allocateBooks(int64_t P[], int64_t n, int64_t x, int64_t m){
    int64_t sum = 0, count = 1;
    for(int64_t i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        sum += P[i];
        if(sum > x){
            count ++;
            sum = P[i];
        }
    }
    return (count <= m);
}
```

Observation, for a particular case : F(lo) = false, F(lo + 1) = false, .. , F(lo + k) = false and F(lo + k + 1) = true, .. , and F(hi) = true.

So, as we can see it is monotonic in nature.

Here we are to find the first true value, (lo + k + 1) in this case. Binary search to the rescue.

```
int main() {
    int64_t n;
    cin >> n;
    int64_t P[n], sum = 0, maxval = 0;
    for(int64_t i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cin >> P[i];
        sum += P[i];
        maxval = max(maxval, P[i]);
    }
    int64_t m;
    cin >> m;

    // find the minimum of max pages in books
    // Observation : when m = 1, ans = sum; while when m = n, ans = maxval
    // Thus when m increases ans decreases
    int64_t lo = maxval, hi = sum, mid;
    while(hi > lo) {
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if(allocateBooks(P, n, mid, m)){
            hi = mid;
        } else {
            lo = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << hi << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the rest of the algorithm? How do you calculate F(x)?

Comment: I suggest you put more smaller code samples in between parts of your explanation.  It may make it clearer how the code corresponds to your description.

Comment: @gukoff added that part. Sorry I missed it earlier.

Comment: Can anyone tell why we are taking the max value as start ?

Answer (score 0):

### Optimizing Book Allocation: A Binary Search Algorithm Approach in Java

---

> **pseudo-code flow for Book Allocation using Binary Search algorithm:**

1. Determine the minimum and maximum possible pages for allocation.
2. Use binary search to find the optimal solution:

   - Calculate the middle value.
   - Check if the middle value is a possible solution.
   - If it is, update the answer and search for a lower possible solution.
   - If it's not, search for a higher possible solution.
3. The possible solution check:

   - Keep track of total pages and student count.
   - Iterate through books and check allocation constraints.
   - If constraints are violated, return false.
   - If all allocations are feasible, return true.
4. Once binary search concludes, the answer represents the minimum pages per student.

> **The Iterative Approach**

```
public static int bookAllocation(int[] arr, int firstIndexValue, int sumOfArr, int numberOfStudent){
        int ans = -1;
        int startIndex = firstIndexValue;
        int endIndex = sumOfArr;

        int mid = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;

        while (startIndex <= endIndex){

            if(isPossibleSolution(arr, mid, numberOfStudent)){
                    ans = mid;
                    endIndex = mid - 1;
            }else {
                    startIndex = mid + 1;
            }
            mid = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
        }

        return ans;
    }

    private static boolean isPossibleSolution(int[] arr, int mid, int numberOfStudent) {

        int totalPages = 0;
        int studentCount = 1;

       for (int page=0; page< arr.length; page++){
           if(arr[page] > mid)
               return false;

           if ((arr[page]+totalPages) > mid){
               studentCount++;
               totalPages = totalPages + arr[page];
           }else{
               totalPages = totalPages + arr[page];
           }
       }
       if(studentCount > numberOfStudent)
           return false;

       return true;
    }
```

**Discover Comprehensive Solution Here**
https://github.com/Amir36036/ds/blob/array/src/main/java/org/ds/array/BookAllocationByBinarySearch.java